# What is the fastest method for importing from the active sheet in Excel to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ado, jet

What is the fastest way to import data into a SQL Server database directly from the active worksheet in Excel?

I have had great success simply looping through the rows and columns, generating a SQL string, opening an ADODB.Connection and executing the SQL. That solution, however, is too slow for large datasets.

So I am testing the Jet Provider with ADO. It's definitely faster, but it requires that the workbook be saved, and I cannot require the user to save the workbook before uploading from it.

The following code works if the workbook has been saved, but if ActiveWorkbook has never been saved ActiveWorkbook.Path returns a null string and the code fails.

```
Sub UploadViaJet()

    Dim objADO As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim lngRecsAff As Long

    Set objADO = New ADODB.Connection

    objADO.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & _
        "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"

    strSQL = "SELECT * INTO [odbc;Driver={SQL Server};" & _
        "Server=<server>;Database=<database>;" & _
        "UID=<UID>;PWD=<PWD>].test_table " & _
        "FROM [" & ActiveSheet.Name & "$]"

    objADO.Execute strSQL, lngRecsAff, adExecuteNoRecords

End Sub
```

Is there a simpler and faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution using Import Excel File**

Since you have a restriction on not forcing the user to save the file, and most proposed solutions require that the file be saved, I would use VBA to

- create a workbook object in memory
- copy paste from active worksheet to workbook
- `SAVEAS` workbook to a temp file name (TempExcelFile.xls) and path
- use Quassnoi's method above to import into SQL Server
- overwrite TempExcelFile.xls with zeroes
- delete TempExcelFile.xls

This way the user will not be forced to save the worksheet, and they will be prompted to save it just like they would during the natural course of their work.

To facilitate multiple active worksheets being simultaneously imported, I would use either a timestamp or a GUID to create the file names.

---

**Solution using ADO Queries**

Have your users create their workbooks from a template that has VBA macros built in Make sure you protect the workbook to prevent unauthorized access to the macros/code behind.

Execute a macro that will loop through the rows and columns, read the cell values, build a SQL query and execute it - use stored procedures with parameters to prevent injection attacks.

Comment: Why not just use the Windows temp file API?

Comment: That's a good idea, except that the question states that user should not be prompted to save the file. So, copy the contents to a different file and use Windows Temp File API would be my choice.

Comment: I have been using ADO distributed queries up to this point. It has worked well for me, but my data sizes have grown to the point the operations run for a long time and sometimes exceed the memory capacity of the computer. Using a temp file seems to be a good solution, even if it requires managing the temp file. Thanks Raj!

Comment: I tested out the Jet method with profiler. It turns out that the Jet method just uses ADO.Command.Prepared and a parametrized query. So I duplicated the query structure in my code and am getting the same performace as Jet, but still have access to the procedure loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a datasource (using a linked server or `OPENROWSET`) and just do a `SELECT` on `SQL Server` side:

```
SELECT  *
INTO    mytable
FROM    OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\myfile.xls', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet$]')
```

The path with the `Excel` workbook should be accessible by the `SQL Server`.

Here is a [**KB article**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686) on how to do this.

Comment: This requires the workbook be uploaded to the server first, correct?

Comment: It should be accessible by the `SQL Server`, that is `UNC` path will work as well. But generally speaking, yes, it should be uploaded.

Comment: Yes, this does require that the file be saved. See my answer for a possible solution to that.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I import large Excel files using SSIS.

Comment: HLGEM, can you elaborate on SSIS? I am looking for a primer on using SSIS with Excel, but have yet to find anything worthwhile. Do you have any sample code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just putting an ActiveWorkBook.SaveAs("some temp filename") at the top, and importing from that?  I do something similar with a macro to FTP the contents of the ActiveSheet to a remote server and it works.